# NestJS: Unique nullable emails violates either not-null constraint or unique constraint

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I want to have the email field in my User class which will be both nullable and unique.
So, I have the following code:

user.entity.ts:

```
export class User
{
    @Column({ name: 'email', nullable: true })
    @Index('users_email_idx', { unique: true })
    email!: string;
...
```

user-create.dto.ts:

```
export class UserCreateDto implements UserInputInterface {

    @IsEmail()
    @IsOptional()
    @MaxLength(255)
    email?: string;

...
```

So when I send the creation request with "email: null", I have the 500 with the message " ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] null value in column "email" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint"

At the same time if I send the existing email there, I have another 500: ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_email_idx"

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in your column entity that this is nullable column:

```
 @Column({ nullable: true })
 @Index('users_email_idx', { unique: true })
 email!: string;
```

Comment: still have  "null value in column "email" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint" unfortunately. I will update the question with your answer but it doesn't work still..

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the DTO of yours To accept null values from the user side this error from your DTO class validator for avoid this you need to use @IsOptional() decorators from a library like class-validator. And by using this modify the    @IsEmail() decorator like this -

```
 @IsEmail({}, { nullable: true })
 @MaxLength(255)
 email?: string;
```

Comment: Argument of type '{ nullable: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidationOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'nullable' does not exist in type 'ValidationOptions'